# Erro para gerar um gráfico Seasplot

Tags: r

gerando este código:

```
inflacao <- ts(read.csv2('inflacao.csv',header = T,sep = ';',dec = ','),
               start = c(1980,01),freq=12)[,-1]
```

depois o Seasplot:

```
seasplot(inflacao, outplot = 4)
```

Dá este erro:

> 1. Relacionar o item
>
> Error in if (diff(range(colSums(ynt))) <= .Machine$double.eps^0.5) { :
>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

Comment: De onde vem a função `seasplot`? Só encontrei no pacote `WRTDStidal` mas essa função não aceita objetos de classe `'ts'` nem de classe `"c('double', 'numeric')"`. Quando utiliza funções que não são funções R base, comece sempre os scripts com `library(pkgname)`.

Comment: o seasplot vem do pacote TStools. vou dar uma verificada.